# Dummy where clauses effects on performance

Tags: sql, performance

What is the effect of having `WHERE 1=1` if you write this request in a script (pseudocode) :

```
sql = "SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM t
       WHERE 1=1" ++ restOfTheClause
```

Where `restOfTheClause` can be a list of field-names/operators/values concatenated with a `AND` :

restOfTheClause = `[('f4','>',5), ('f5','IN(1,2,3)'), ('f10','=',1)].map(writeWherePart).join(' AND ')`

Writing `WHERE 1=1` allows to write simpler code because you don't have to check if your `restOfTheClause` is empty or not, etc.

What is the effect on performance with this clause ?
What is the difference between having `WHERE 1=1` and having no where clause at all ?

I work on Oracle since a couple of months and i found i have to put `WHERE 1=1` but other RDBMS accept `WHERE true`. As `=` is an operator, is there any performance differences between oracle and other RDBMS in using dummy clauses ?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on DBMS and version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server and oracle are sophisticated enough to completely delete this clause. It is deleted as a simplification step. It has no perf impact whatsoever. I don't know about other RDBMS'es.

Answer (score 3):

The optimiser is smart enough to realize that 1=1 needs to be computed only once, so the performance impact is negligible.